# Differentiability conditions for this function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

I'm trying to show the differentiability for a certain function $f:D\subset \mathbb{R^{d}}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$. I've already know that for every $x\in D$ there exist a unique $C^{1}$ function, let's say, $\alpha_{x}:B_{\delta}(x)\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$, such that $f(y)=\alpha(y)$, for every $y\in B_{\delta}(x)$.
So, is this enough to guarantee that $f$ is a $C^{1}$ function? or does it depend on the domain $D$?

I would appreciate if someone can help me clarify this question.

Comment: To check whether a function is $C^1$ is a local matter.

Comment: That's right! I was thinking if there might be a problem if, for example, $D$ was not bounded or something or can we already claim that $f$ is differentiable regardless of the domain? Thanks for answer.

Comment: Only if you're trying to get some sort of uniform estimate (like showing the function is Lipschitz) will compactness become an issue.